# Why is this directed graph strongly connected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From what I can see, there is no vertex path that goes to 1 so why is it strongly connected? Shouldnt every vertex be reachable from every other vertex? In this picture the 1 is not reachable.

[image]

Comment: There are no arrows on the (1,4) edge. So you can go in both directions there?

Comment: AHHHH, yes if I recall it means (1,4) and (4,1), but ny book says that it is loop free so...?

Comment: nvm, you are right thanks for reminding me and ignore what i said about the loop. tiredness + math = crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is only an edge from 4 to 1 the graph is strongly connected so your book might actually be right about "no loops"